# Best practices of Export/Import Keycloak data in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to figure out, what is import/export best practices in K8S keycloak(version 3.3.0.CR1). Here is keycloak official page [import/export](http://www.keycloak.org/docs/2.0/server_admin_guide/topics/export-import.html) explanation, and they example of export to single file json. Going to /keycloak/bin folder and the run this:

```
./standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile -Dkeycloak.migration.file=keycloak-export.json
```

I logged in to pod, and I get errors after run this command:

```
12:23:32,045 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.management.http.extensible" => "java.net.BindException: Address already in use /127.0.0.1:9990"},
    "WFLYCTL0288: One or more services were unable to start due to one or more indirect dependencies not being available." => {
        "Services that were unable to start:" => ["org.wildfly.management.http.extensible.shutdown"],
        "Services that may be the cause:" => ["jboss.remoting.remotingConnectorInfoService.http-remoting-connector"]
    }
}
```

As I see, Keycloak server run on the same port, where I ran backup script. Here helm/keycloak values.yml:

```
Service:
  Name: keycloak
  Port: 8080
  Type: ClusterIP

Deployment:
  Image: jboss/keycloak
  ImageTag: 2.5.1.Final
  ImagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  ContainerPort: 8080
  KeycloakUser: Admin
  KeycloakPassword: Admin
```

So, server should be stopped, before we ran this scripts? I can't stop keycloak process inside of pod, because ingress will close pod and will create new one.
Any suggestions for any other way to export/import(backup/restore) data? Or I missing something?

P.S.
I even tried UI import/export. Export work good, and I see all data. But import worked in half way. He Brought me all "Clients", but not my "Realm" and "User Federation".

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Basically, you just have to start the exporting Keycloak instance on ports that are different from your main instance. I used something like this just now:

`bin/standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=singleFile -Dkeycloak.migration.file=keycloak-export.json -Djboss.http.port=8888 -Djboss.https.port=9999 -Djboss.management.http.port=7777`

The important part are all the ports. If you get more error messages, you might need to add more properties (`grep port standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` is your friend for finding out property names), but in the end, all error messages stop and you see this message instead:

`09:15:26,550 INFO  [org.keycloak.exportimport.singlefile.SingleFileExportProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 52) Exporting model into file /opt/jboss/keycloak/keycloak-export.json
[...]
09:15:29,565 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: Keycloak 3.2.0.Final (WildFly Core 2.0.10.Final) started in 12156ms - Started 444 of 818 services (558 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)`

Now you can stop the server with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, exit the container and copy the export file away with `kubectl cp`.

Comment: Yes, yes, thank you so much for that. Had already gave up when I came across your answer. Perfect.

Comment: You can also use `-Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset` to offset all ports

Answer (score 1):

The Export functionality changed with the Quarkus distribution.

See [Documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/server/importExport).

Be aware, that there is a bug, when the InfinispanCache is enabled. In short, the port for the cache is blocked, when trying to export.
[Keycloak Issue](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/14733)
[Bitnami Issue, with workaround](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/13105)